# google map showing location from property form

Tags: google-maps, properties

I am trying to make a form for showing properties:
My form looks like this below, how can i get the google map to show the location of the property?

```
            <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_IPROPERTY_LOCATION'); ?></legend>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('hide_address'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('hide_address'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('street_num'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('street_num'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('street'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('street'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('street2'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('street2'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('apt'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('apt'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('city'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('city'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('postcode'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('postcode'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('locstate'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('locstate'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('province'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('province'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('country'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('country'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('region'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('region'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('county'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('county'); ?></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_IPROPERTY_DRAG_AND_DROP' ); ?></legend> 
            <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('geocode_header'); ?>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('latitude'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('latitude'); ?></div>
            <div class="formelm"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('longitude'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('longitude'); ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $this->form->getInput('google_map'); ?></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Google Map and add a marker on top of it. It seems you have already got the latitude and longitude, so creating the map should be quite simple like in [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=en). This should be a starting point for your further development of your map.

```
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $this->form->getInput('latitude'); ?>,<?php echo $this->form->getInput('longitude'); ?>);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
```